# Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded Laravel 4 error

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-4

I am having an issue with a certain function that sends a password request within my UserController in laravel 4. It checks to see if the email exists in the database then sends an email if the user does. The function then creates a token in a table and sends that at the end of the link within the email.

The function works as for as creating the token in the database but it seems to have an issue because i keep getting the `Maximum execution time` error. I do not know what is causing this, it seems to have something to do with the redirect. Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance!

Here is the controller function:

```
public function passwordRequest()
    {
        $data = [
            "requested"=>Input::old("requested")
        ];

        if(Input::server("REQUEST_METHOD") == "POST") {

            $input = Input::all();
            $rules = [
                "email" => "required|exists:users,email"
            ];
            $v = Validator::make($input, $rules);

            if($v->passes()) {
                $credentials = [
                    "email" => Input::get("email"),
                ];

                Password::remind($credentials, function($message, $user) {
                    $message->from("request@test.com");
                });

                $data["requested"] = true;

                return Redirect::route("user/request")->with($data);
            }

            return Redirect::to(URL::route("user/request"))->withInput($data)->withErrors($v);
        }

        return View::make("user/request", $data);
    }
```

here is the routes.php file:

```
Route::group(["before"=>"guest"], function() {
    Route::any("/", [
        "as"=>"user/login",
        "uses"=>"UserController@userLogin"
    ]);

    Route::any("/request", [
        "as"=>"user/request",
        "uses"=>"UserController@passwordRequest"
    ]);

    Route::any("/reset", [
        "as"=>"user/reset",
        "uses"=>"UserController@passwordReset"
    ]);

    Route::any("/register", [
        "as" => "user/register", 
        "uses" => "UserController@userRegister"
    ]);
})

;
```

here is the view if needed:

```
@extends("layouts.master")

@section("content")
<h1>Request Password Reset</h1>

{{ Form::open([
    "route"=>"user/request",
    "autocomplete"=>"off"
]) }}

    @if(isset($errors))
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <div class="error">
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    @endif

    @if(Session::has("requested"))
        <div class="success">
            <li>An email has been sent with your password reset request.</li>
        </div>
        {{ Session::forget('requested') }}
    @endif
    <br />
    {{ Form::label("email", "Email:") }}
    {{ Form::text("email", Input::old("email"), [
        "placeholder"=>"Email Address"
    ]) }}

    {{ Form::submit("Reset") }}

{{ Form::close() }}
<br />
{{ HTML::linkRoute("user/login", "Return to Login") }}
@stop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was actually in the wifi I was using. I dissconnected from it and connected to another one and everything worked just fine. I have never had this issue where a wifi will not let the localhost send an email. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 27):

Your script executed for more then `30` seconds and was terminated and not related to `Laravel` but `php`. The default limit is `30` seconds, stored in `php.ini` file. To temporarily extend the time limit, you may use following line if code in your current script, but try to optimize your script too (if possible)

```
set_time_limit(60); //60 seconds = 1 minute
```

[Read more on php manual.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

> You can do set_time_limit(0); so that the script will run forever -
>   however this is not recommended and your web server might catch you
>   out with an imposed HTTP timeout (usually around 5 minutes).

You may also use

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 60);
```

[Check ini_set.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

Comment: how can i add set_time_limit in laravel rather than php.ini?

Comment: @AbhishekKumar, In a service provider, probably in the appserviceprovider.