# Small file get uploaded but not large file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this action in controler

```
    public function upload() {
  // getting all of the post data
  $file = array('image' => Input::file('image'));
  //return $file;
  // setting up rules
  $rules = array('image' => 'required'); //mimes:jpeg,bmp,png and for max size max:10000
  // doing the validation, passing post data, rules and the messages
  $validator = Validator::make($file, $rules);
  if ($validator->fails()) {
    // send back to the page with the input data and errors
   // return Redirect::to('upload')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
   return "error validation";
  }
  else {
    // checking file is valid.
    if (Input::file('image')->isValid()) {
      $destinationPath = 'myuploads'; // upload path
      $extension = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
      $fileName = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
     // $fileName = rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extension; // renameing image
      Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath, $fileName); // uploading file to given path

      return "upload success";
    }
    else {
      // sending back with error message.
      Session::flash('error', 'uploaded file is not valid');
      return "error";
    }
  }
}
```

It works for small file size like 2MB but won't work for 4MB file size.
For 4MB or more it gets error in validation.In the code above there's this code

```
 if ($validator->fails()) {

       return "error validation";
      }
```

It gives this custom error `error validation`. I have already worked on configuring php.ini for max upload limit and post limit.

Comment: I know you've set the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in `php.ini` but have you checked that these settings are being applied? I have often found that settings in php.ini are being overridden elsewhere, what does `ini_get('post_max_size')` return?

Comment: Have you checked the `max_execution_time` and increased the default value too? [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19796540/2780063)

Comment: What do you get when looking at `$validator->messages();`?

Comment: @Chelsea have you set validation rule in your model. refer this link [laravel validation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation) and set your file size validation like 
$rules = array('file' => 'required|max:10000|mimes:doc,docx')

Comment: What is extension in small file? And in big file? May be extension big file is wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well I found the answer, The things mentioned above to make change in php.ini about `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` are infact the only thing to solve the problem mentioned by the question.

The only problem was that I am using wamp and apparently wamp has multiple php.ini files one in php folder and one in apache folder. I made changes in PHP folder when the change should be made to the one inside apache folder.

Comment: None of the answers helped solve my problem..what do I do, maybe some one would update their answer so that I could award.

Comment: @Chelsea what is the difference between your answer and the one `phuti` gave, because all you neeeded was to change `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in multiple files.i'm surprised you did not mark his answer, instead you post an answer with what he has suggested.

Comment: @LetmeSuckitBaby  well before asking question I did did little research and I knew I had to change upload_max_filesize and post_max_size and I did that too and still it was not working that's why I posted this question.Just look at the last part of the question I have mentioned the php.ini is updated as required and still not working. Any way I am more than happy to  reward if the answer is updated.

Comment: In my case, the php.ini file which was actually 'acting' was the one inside the program files(x86)

Answer (score 64):

Other answers refers saying only about the [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.php) directiress.

I would like to give answer considering both php.ini and the [Laravel Validation Rule](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation)

First check your `php.ini`

For the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` and change to your desired file size

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```

You shall have your rule like this

```
public static $updaterules = array(
    'uploadedimage' => 'image|max:5000'            
    );
```

Additional information :

You shall check for the file format for image by

```
'uploaded' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png'
```

Read more about [Laravel validation here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation)

### Update :

**As the questioner didn't noticed which php.ini file is being used by the server. I am updating my answer accordingly so it might be useful for someone who has similar problems in future**

To find the full configuration about the php.ini file which is currently being used by your server.

For Linux

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

For Windows

```
php -i | find /i "Configuration File"
```

From a php file

i.e.,

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: It didn't work until I added / uncommented the temporary directory in php.ini: 

upload_tmp_dir = /upload-tmp-dir

Comment: Are you using linux machine ?

Answer (score 13):

edit your `php.ini` file and set:

```
memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 70M
post_max_size = 100M
```

and restart apache.

Comment: memory_limit 256 helped me (default 128)

Answer (score 4):

For laravel apps running on nginx..

1. Identify your php ini file:

   > php -i | grep php.ini
2. Edit both the cli and the fpm files to be sure:

   > vim /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
   >
   > vim /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini
3. Change these to your prefered limits:

   > post_max_size = 1G
   >
   > upload_max_filesize = 1G
   >
   > memory_limit = 1G
4. Restart php fpm

   > service php7.2-fpm restart
5. Reload nginx

   > service nginx reload

Comment: cli ini work for me . tnx

Answer (score 0):

Check `max_file_uploads` and `max_post_size` in `php.ini`. It shows from `phpinfo()`

Comment: post_max_size = 100M & upload_max_filesize = 70M

Comment: @Chelsea After editing your `php.ini` did you run `service apache2 restart` or  `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: I restarted all wamp services including mysql and apache

Comment: Set memory_limit to 1G to be sure !

Answer (score 0):

FOR WAMP SERVER:
Go to `/wamp64/bin/apache/apache(your version)/bin/` and open `php.symlink(.ini)`
and change
`post_max_size,memory_limit,upload_max_filesize` as per your need.
and **restart the wamp server**.