# Laravel large size image upload validator not work

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, ini

I'm using **Laravel: 5.2.*** with **PHP Version 5.6.4** as my project and trying to validate/restrict large size(`max:600kb`) image(Single file) with form uploader.

While submit form with large size image(i.e. **8 MB**), redirect me on home page without performing validation OR exception message. So I checked at log-viwer and found some thing `exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException'`.

**I tried number of solution, some of the listed below**
- [Small file get uploaded but not large file in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28529518/small-file-get-uploaded-but-not-large-file-in-laravel)
- [File validation failing on larger files](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/file-validation-failing-on-larger-files?page=1)
- [L4.0, (CSRF) TokenMismatchException when uploading large files](http://laravel.io/forum/02-20-2014-l40-csrf-tokenmismatchexception-when-uploading-large-files) (I know this is for L4)

Further forms, route, request and all other stuffs are working fine with small size so I think not an issue with code. Also I changed php.ini as per require and restart the apache but getting hard luck.

**Current `php.ini`**

```
upload_max_filesize = 1G
post_max_size = 2G
```

**Loaded Configuration File**(`php.ini` path)

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

My problem is why large size image not work as small size for my project? Please help me.
**P.S.** I appreciate your help/assistance.

**UPDATE (2016/12/22)**
I have reviewed and found the question [similar like me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28529518/small-file-get-uploaded-but-not-large-file-in-laravel) but answer still not work for me. Any Idea! Please help!

Comment: Can you double  check with `php -i | grep php.ini` for exact `php.ini` location or do `phpinfo();` for exact file path?

Comment: If php.ini file is correct path, can you update your question for your validation rules?

Comment: @KelvinKyaw: `php.ini` location is correct. See: `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` Further my question already something like `validator not work`, Still need correction?

Comment: One more stupid question. Are you using apache or nginx ?

Comment: @KelvinKyaw No worries! `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` so apache.

Answer (score 0):

can you please check after commenting

`\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,`

in kernel.php in Http folder. If thats the issue you can try the below solution

Add `{!! csrf_token() !!}` within your form to generate a CSRF token. And pass it as a hidden field

You can try this as in laravel there is a middleware for csrf token.

Hope this works.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I already said that **stuffs are working fine with small size** so I think their is no need to use  as you suggested. can you please explain why use CSRF this way?

Comment: It just for security purpose so as to check all the values are with respect to that particular form.

Comment: I guess you might have done but just for confirmation did you restart Apache service after changing the values.

Comment: I restarted but no luck