# The file exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive (limit is 2048 KiB) in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I'm getting the above error in my development environment when i try to upload an image. I have followed other answers here by doing the following

- Setting the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size
- Restart wamp server
- Shutdown system and restarted the system

but i still can't get past the error. Am I doing anything wrong? Below is the relevant section from my php.ini file

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 100M

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20

; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = 125M
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found a solution for wamp, click on the wamp icon -> PHP -> PHP settings and set both upload_max_filesize and post_max_size. This will automatically set the values in the actuall php.ini being loaded by apache. Then restart wamp services. I hope this helps someone save the hours i spent trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 12):

If you're using LAMP (Apache server), you need to edit both `/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini` and `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini`.

Properties to edit to the desired values (ex. 10 Megabytes):

1. upload_max_filesize: default is 2M (Megabytes)

   `; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
   ; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
   upload_max_filesize = 10M`
2. post_max_size: default is 8M (Megabytes)

   `; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
   ; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
   ; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
   ; http://php.net/post-max-size
   post_max_size = 10M`

After saving the `php.ini` files, run:
`sudo service apache2 restart`

Note: before editing the `php.ini` values, ensure that `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini` is the loaded php configuration file. The command is: `php -i | grep php.ini`

Answer (score 5):

I agree with you. I am developing a project with Laravel, and the PHP version I use is 7.2, but the `upload_max_filesize = 100M` line that I was changing when I made changes from the WAMP server was the php.ini file for PHP 5.

I created a blank page in my project and found where the php.ini file was with the `phpinfo()` command.

File path in me: `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.4\php.ini`

And I was shocked when I saw that the line `upload_max_filesize` was 2M. When I made the change, I restarted the services and I am happy!

Answer (score -1):

Are you changing the right php.ini file? Those WAMP installations can be tricky.
You can use a `phpinfo()` function to see the correct paths.

**Duplicate of:** [Small file get uploaded but not large file in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28529518/small-file-get-uploaded-but-not-large-file-in-laravel)

Comment: I went through that question earlier and I also checked the phpinfo() (as suggested by other questions) and edited the php.ini file in the "Loaded Configuration File" path. That's the reason I posted my question showing what i have done so far