# Laravel Image Upload Problems

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a really weird problem

If I upload image less than 2 Mb(I don't know exact size) , there is not problem and if i print as dd;

```
UploadedFile {#530
  -test: false
  -originalName: "20170607_132957.jpg"
  -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
  -size: 883421
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "/tmp"
  filename: "phpx8aY57"
  basename: "phpx8aY57"
  pathname: "/tmp/phpx8aY57"
  extension: ""
  realPath: "/tmp/phpx8aY57"
  aTime: 2017-10-09 06:12:07
  mTime: 2017-10-09 06:12:07
  cTime: 2017-10-09 06:12:07
  inode: 35785
  size: 883421
  perms: 0100600
  owner: 33
  group: 33
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
}
```

But if I try upload image more than 2 mb and print as dd function();

```
UploadedFile {#530
  -test: false
  -originalName: "IMG_20171004_193910~3.jpg"
  -mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
  -size: 0
  -error: 1
  #hashName: null
  path: ""
  filename: ""
  basename: ""
  pathname: ""
  extension: ""
  realPath: "/var/www/api/test/public"
  aTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  mTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  cTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  inode: false
  size: false
  perms: 00
  owner: false
  group: false
  type: false
  writable: false
  readable: false
  executable: false
  file: false
  dir: false
  link: false
}
```

There's not filename. And mimeType is looking application/octet-stream.

I tried raise system's upload size by php.ini but it's not working. And I need advice. Thank you.

---

I upload files to system as form-data

System: PHP 7.1 , Laravel 5.4

Comment: It seems you have default php 2mb upload limit. Exame php.ini upload section.

Comment: I wish I could mark as a duplicate Here is the reference
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28529518/small-file-get-uploaded-but-not-large-file-in-laravel

Comment: @IvanBolnikh I wrote 70mb on this conf

Comment: @JayminNoob I saw this post and I tried what they advice but it does not work.

Comment: i have the same problem :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you changed both parameters in config file?:

```
post_max_size = 128M
upload_max_filesize = 128M
```

Comment: post_max_size = 100M 
upload_max_filesize = 70M

Now there is wrote

Comment: This took so long to figure out the issue. Thanks. THIS WORKS FINE

Answer (score 0):

Use image intervention for image upload in laravel, Refer Docs,
http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation

Comment: I think the problem is php sided. Image does not come in temp folder

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problems. I tried to write wrong file path.

I printed php.ini --v on ubuntu server and server back file path as /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini but I printed phpinfo() function in index.php and I saw  /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini.

I don't know why they are different. I suppose they are same but they weren't.